# xml-rpc redstone: how can the xml-rpc messages be viewed?

Tags: message, xml-rpc

Using redstone.xmlrpc.XmlRpcClient and redstone.xmlrpc.XmlRpcServlet, how can I see the actual xml-rpc messages that are being sent back and forth?  Is there some configuration setting that needs to be set?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used RawCap to collect the traffic and then used Wireshark to view the traffic giving the filter 'http and xml'